# Getting name="" from div with $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html

i am trying to get `$_POST["number"]` from `<div name="number" class="total"></div>` class total is attached with
`

```
var count = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
    count++;
  count > 3 || $('.total').append($(this).val());
});`
```

When i try to get the `$_POST["number"]` **Notice: Undefined index: number in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 67**

EDIT:

If that won't work how i can get that JQuery value inside  to that value=""

Thanks to @Barry Thomas for helping me. Here is the fix:

**FORM**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    Name <input name="name" type="text"></input> <br /><br />
    Number <div id="codebar">
    <input type="hidden" name="number" id="form_number" value="">
    <div id="div_number" class="total"></div>
</div>
<br>

<input name="submit" type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var count = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
    count++;
  count > 3 || $('.total').text($(this).val());
  $('#form_number').val($('#div_number').text());

});
```

Comment: only input/textarea/select-type FORM elements will submit as part of a form. divs aren't form elements. Therefore the div's name is useless for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well how i can get that JQuery value inside `<input type="hidden" value="">` to that value=""

Comment: Please go through a basic HTML/Javascript/jQuery tutorial. What you are asking are fundamental and covered by any decent introduction. Take the time to actually _learn_ what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    Name <input name="name" type="text"></input> <br /><br />
    Number <div id="codebar">
    <input type="hidden" id="form_number" value="">
<div name="number" id="div_number" class="total"></div>
</div>
<br>

<input name="submit" type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Move the name="number" on to the input, like so.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    Name <input name="name" type="text"></input> <br /><br />
    Number <div id="codebar">
    <input type="hidden" name="number" id="form_number" value="">
    <div id="div_number" class="total"></div>
</div>
<br>

<input name="submit" type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

The form input was missing name="number" so when it posted there was no $_POST['number']

```
var count = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
    count++;
  count > 3 || $('.total').text($(this).val());
  **$('#form_number').val($('#div_number').text());**

});
```

Comment: If it should work with

`var count = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
 count++;
  count > 3 || $('.total').append($(this).val()) || $('#form_number').val($('#div_number').text());;

});`

then it did not worked.

Comment: Can you post your html with the form?

Comment: It would look ugly if i would post the code here so i made a pastebin of almost the whole code http://pastebin.com/9EgdgPQf **I removed** `$('#form_number').val($('#div_number').text());` **part for sure**

Comment: Did not worked, i tried var_dump and got this `string(0) "" `

Comment: Oh i forgot to add `$('#form_number').val($('#div_number').text());`

Comment: Ok, so there was another part that needed changing, updated again.

Comment: Ah ok :) Working now so?

Comment: Yep. Thanks again.